# Why can I only append an array of tuples using tuple names directly if the values are `let` constants -- Swift

Tags: swift, tuples

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
typealias SomeTuple = (string: String, int: Int)

var tupleArray: [SomeTuple] = []

// Fails
// tupleArray.append(string: "Hello", int: 42)

// Works
let string = "Hello"
let num = 42
tupleArray.append(string: string, int: num)

// Fails
// var varString = "Hi Again"
// var varNum = 234
// tupleArray.append(string: varString, int: varNum)
```

Why does the `.append(tupleName: val, anotherTupleName: anotherVal)` syntax only work when the values are declared previously as `let` constants?

**Note:**

I'm aware that I could wrap my tuples in an extra parenthetical like this:

```
tupleArray.append((string: "Hey", int: 234))
```

My question is why don't I have to do that with `let` constants.

Comment: Interestingly `tupleArray.append(string: "Hello" as String, int: 42 as Int)` works

Comment: @sbooth - Good find, that makes this whole thing even stranger!  (noticed that it also works for `var` types if you specify like that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`swiftc -dump-ast` unveils some possible reasons.

Let's start with simplified code:

```
let string = "Hello"
let num = 42
var varString = "Hi Again"
var varNum = 234 

typealias SomeTuple = (string: String, int: Int)
func foo(x:SomeTuple) {}
```

### Error cases

```
foo(string: "Hello", int: 42)
```

```
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (call_expr type='()' location=test.swift:9:1 range=[test.swift:9:1 - line:9:29]
        (declref_expr type='(SomeTuple) -> ()' location=test.swift:9:1 range=[test.swift:9:1 - line:9:1] decl=test.(file).foo@test.swift:2:6 specialized=no)
        (tuple_expr type='<<error type>>' location=test.swift:9:4 range=[test.swift:9:4 - line:9:29] names=string,int
          (string_literal_expr type='<<error type>>' location=test.swift:9:13 range=[test.swift:9:13 - line:9:13] encoding=utf8 value="Hello")
          (integer_literal_expr type='<<error type>>' location=test.swift:9:27 range=[test.swift:9:27 - line:9:27] value=42))))
```

In this case, the compiler cannot infer final type of `string_literal_expr` and `integer_literal_expr`. `string_literal_expr` can be `String`, `StaticString`, `Selector` or such.

```
foo(string: varString, int: varNum)
```

```
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (call_expr type='()' location=test.swift:10:1 range=[test.swift:10:1 - line:10:35]
        (declref_expr type='(SomeTuple) -> ()' location=test.swift:10:1 range=[test.swift:10:1 - line:10:1] decl=test.(file).foo@test.swift:2:6 specialized=no)
        (tuple_expr type='(string: @lvalue String, int: @lvalue Int)' location=test.swift:10:4 range=[test.swift:10:4 - line:10:35] names=string,int
          (declref_expr type='@lvalue String' location=test.swift:10:13 range=[test.swift:10:13 - line:10:13] decl=test.(file).varString@test.swift:6:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no)
          (declref_expr type='@lvalue Int' location=test.swift:10:29 range=[test.swift:10:29 - line:10:29] decl=test.(file).varNum@test.swift:7:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no))))
```

In this case, the compiler interpreted `(string: varString, int: varNum)` as `(string: @lvalue String, int: @lvalue Int)`. And it does not match with `(string: String, int: Int)`.

### Success cases

```
foo(string: "Hello" as String, int: 42 as Int)
```

```
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (call_expr type='()' location=test.swift:13:1 range=[test.swift:13:1 - line:13:46]
        (declref_expr type='(SomeTuple) -> ()' location=test.swift:13:1 range=[test.swift:13:1 - line:13:1] decl=test.(file).foo@test.swift:2:6 specialized=no)
        (tuple_expr type='(string: String, int: Int)' location=test.swift:13:4 range=[test.swift:13:4 - line:13:46] names=string,int
          (coerce_expr type='String' location=test.swift:13:21 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:24] writtenType=String
            (call_expr implicit type='String' location=test.swift:13:13 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:13]
              (constructor_ref_call_expr implicit type='(_builtinStringLiteral: RawPointer, byteSize: Word, isASCII: Int1) -> String' location=test.swift:13:13 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:13]
                (declref_expr implicit type='String.Type -> (_builtinStringLiteral: RawPointer, byteSize: Word, isASCII: Int1) -> String' location=test.swift:13:13 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:13] decl=Swift.(file).String.init(_builtinStringLiteral:byteSize:isASCII:) specialized=no)
                (type_expr implicit type='String.Type' location=test.swift:13:13 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:13] typerepr='<<IMPLICIT>>'))
              (string_literal_expr type='(_builtinStringLiteral: Builtin.RawPointer, byteSize: Builtin.Word, isASCII: Builtin.Int1)' location=test.swift:13:13 range=[test.swift:13:13 - line:13:13] encoding=utf8 value="Hello")))
          (coerce_expr type='Int' location=test.swift:13:40 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:43] writtenType=Int
            (call_expr implicit type='Int' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37]
              (constructor_ref_call_expr implicit type='(_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048) -> Int' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37]
                (declref_expr implicit type='Int.Type -> (_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048) -> Int' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37] decl=Swift.(file).Int.init(_builtinIntegerLiteral:) specialized=no)
                (type_expr implicit type='Int.Type' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37] typerepr='<<IMPLICIT>>'))
              (tuple_expr implicit type='(_builtinIntegerLiteral: Int2048)' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37] names=_builtinIntegerLiteral
                (integer_literal_expr type='Int2048' location=test.swift:13:37 range=[test.swift:13:37 - line:13:37] value=42)))))))
```

Explicit cast causes `coerce_expr`. And it constructs `String` and `Int` correctly.

```
 foo(string: string, int: num)
```

```
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (call_expr type='()' location=test.swift:12:1 range=[test.swift:12:1 - line:12:29]
        (declref_expr type='(SomeTuple) -> ()' location=test.swift:12:1 range=[test.swift:12:1 - line:12:1] decl=test.(file).foo@test.swift:2:6 specialized=no)
        (tuple_expr type='(string: String, int: Int)' location=test.swift:12:4 range=[test.swift:12:4 - line:12:29] names=string,int
          (declref_expr type='String' location=test.swift:12:13 range=[test.swift:12:13 - line:12:13] decl=test.(file).string@test.swift:4:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no)
          (declref_expr type='Int' location=test.swift:12:26 range=[test.swift:12:26 - line:12:26] decl=test.(file).num@test.swift:5:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no))))
```

`let` constants are `String` and `Int`, it does not have `@lvalue`. So they can be applied AS IS.

```
foo((string: varString, int: varNum))
```

```
  (top_level_code_decl
    (brace_stmt
      (call_expr type='()' location=test.swift:15:1 range=[test.swift:15:1 - line:15:37]
        (declref_expr type='(SomeTuple) -> ()' location=test.swift:15:1 range=[test.swift:15:1 - line:15:1] decl=test.(file).foo@test.swift:2:6 specialized=no)
        (paren_expr type='(SomeTuple)' location=test.swift:15:5 range=[test.swift:15:4 - line:15:37]
          (tuple_expr type='(string: String, int: Int)' location=test.swift:15:5 range=[test.swift:15:5 - line:15:36] names=string,int
            (load_expr implicit type='String' location=test.swift:15:14 range=[test.swift:15:14 - line:15:14]
              (declref_expr type='@lvalue String' location=test.swift:15:14 range=[test.swift:15:14 - line:15:14] decl=test.(file).varString@test.swift:6:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no))
            (load_expr implicit type='Int' location=test.swift:15:30 range=[test.swift:15:30 - line:15:30]
              (declref_expr type='@lvalue Int' location=test.swift:15:30 range=[test.swift:15:30 - line:15:30] decl=test.(file).varNum@test.swift:7:5 direct_to_storage specialized=no)))))))
```

In this case, compared to `foo(string: varString, int: varNum)`, `load_expr` is inserted, and it converts `@lvalue String` to `String`, and `@lvalue Int` to `Int`

Comment: This is a great answer.  I didn't know about the `-dump-ast` option to `swift` either.